# How to mix of using ng-repeat & ng-if on td

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm looking forward to the way to mix `ng-repeat` and `ng-if` on td

Before:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.items">
    <td>{{ item.A }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.B }}</td>
    <td ng-if="condition">//other template here</td>
    <td>{{ item.D }}</td>
</tr>
```

I have some table template like this. I want to create a table component for re-useable where the table generated by rows & columns's meta. Something like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in $ctrl.rows">
  <td ng-repeat="col in $ctrl.columns">

  </td>
</tr>
```

But I don't know how to combine two syntax, cause I can't put `<div>` inside `td` to add the `ng-if` on it

Comment: You could do `<td ng-repeat="col in $ctrl.columns" ng-if="condition">`, but I don't think I quite understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Question is unclear.

Comment: @ExplosionPills: I have some table template like this. I want to create a table component for reuseable where the table generated by rows & columns's meta